# How can I make turtle follow the mouse cursor in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am making a drawing program with Python turtle graphics. And I have some problem on control turtles with mouse.

I want the turtle to follow the cursor without click. But I want to make the turtle draw the line when I click left mouse button.

I googled for this problem. But I can't find the answer.

Here is my code:

```py
import turtle as t

def draw_pen(x, y):

    t.ondrag(None)
    t.pendown()
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y))
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.ondrag(draw_pen)

def dragging(x, y):
    t.ondrag(None)
    t.penup()
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y))
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.ondrag(dragging)


t.onscreenclick(draw_pen, 1)
t.ondrag(dragging)
```

Comment: Please provide also definition of `t` which is used in your code

Comment: Oops sorrry. I import turtle as `t`

Comment: you would have to use [ontimer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) to execute code every few milliseconds - and this function should get current mouse position and use it to move turtle.

Comment: I think `turtle` is not good for this. It doesn't have functions like `onscreenrelease` or `onmousemove`. `turtle` is build on top of `tkinter` and it would need to access `tkinter` `Canvas` and use `tkinter` `bind` for this. And maybe it would be simpler to do it directly with `tkinter`